# Get All exceptions in Command Line Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have a command that runs with Cron, and i Want to create file with logs. 
In that file i write the successfully log and I want to write also the exception logs and I want to see the logs to console, if i launch my command manually

I created the service like this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/logging.html) But I don't see any log and any error in my console

I don't Understand what i have to do after create the service

my command is Simple and extends `ContainerAwareCommand`

class CreateXmlCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand

```
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('foo')
            );

    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        //stuff

    }
}
```

I Want to get also FatalErrorException and write it in my file

Answer (score 0):

To catch fatals, etc... pre PHP7, you'll need to setup an error hander, to catch the errors, and throw an exception yourself. E.g.

```
function exception_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $severity)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    $message = sprintf('Error: %s, occured in (%s) on line (%s)', $message, $file, $line);

    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
}
```

Then once you have your function you need to register it

```
set_error_handler('exception_error_handler');
```

Answer (score -1):

A fatal error isn't an exception, not until PHP 7! You can't "catch" it.

Comment: you are right, and how can Get the error the i Find in `app/logs/dev.log` thanks to service command http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/logging.html ?

Comment: This is incorrect anyway, I'll post the answer for those who come